# How to tell if a SCSI device is removable?

Tags: linux, block-device, scsi, removable-storage

In DMESG I see:

`[sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk`

1. How does Linux decide what is removable and not removable?
2. Is there a way I can look up if a device is "removable" or not other than the log, for example somehwere in /sys or /proc?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All  block devices have a `removable` attribute, among other [block device attributes](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.14.1/block/genhd.c#L979). These attributes can be read from userland in [sysfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysfs) at `/sys/block/DEVICE/ATTRIBUTE`, e.g. `/sys/block/sdb/removable`.

You can query this attribute from a udev rule, with `ATTR{removable}=="0"` or `ATTR{removable}=="1"`.

Note that removable (the device keeps existing but may have no media) isn't the same thing as hotpluggable (the device can come and go). For example, CD drives are removable but often not hotpluggable. USB flash drives are both, but hard disks in external enclosures are typically hotpluggable but not removable.

If you want to find out the nitty-gritty of when a device is considered removable, you'll have to dig into the [kernel source](http://lxr.linux.no/linux). Search for `removable` — there aren't too many spurious hits. For SCSI devices, the `removable` bit is read from the device in [`scsi_add_lun`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.14.1/drivers/scsi/scsi_scan.c#L732) with a [SCSI INQUIRY command](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/archived/SCSI-Programming-HOWTO/SCSI-Programming-HOWTO-9.html).

Answer (score 2):

With a little effort I found the answer to my second question:

`cat /sys/block/sda/removable`

Comment: Also considering just using fstatfs and checking the fs type