# Which mountpoint paths will automatically show up in file browser under devices?

Tags: mount, desktop-environment, nautilus, pcmanfm, file-browser

Some examples:

- If I plug an external USB drive in, it will get mounted under `/media/$USER/<device-id>` and my file browsers will automatically list the mountpoint under devices.
- The same will happen if I manually mount something into a regular folder in my home directory. However, my file browsers will not list the mountpoint if that folder is hidden.
- The file browser also won't list mountpoints that are in `/tmp`, for example.

So what are the conditions for a mountpoint to automatically show up in file browsers under devices? Since PCManFM and Nautilus seemingly behave exactly the same, I believe there might be general rules for this? Can I "force" a mountpoint (which is a hidden folder or in `/tmp`, for example) to show up under devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Block devices have a flag to indicate whether they are removable.  This can be seen in the output of `lsblk --help`.  Although I did not check the kernel sources, the device module is the best place to set this flag.

The exclusion of file systems mounted under `/tmp` is probably a separate check by the file managers you tried, or the libraries they use.  Dolphin, for instance, continues to show such mounts as removable drives.

```
Usage:
 lsblk [options] [<device> ...]

List information about block devices.

Options:
 ...
 -o, --output <list>  output columns
 ...

Available output columns:
 ...
           RM  removable device
 ...
```

[PCManFM](https://github.com/lxqt/pcmanfm-qt) uses [GLib and Gio](https://github.com/GNOME/glib/) libraries.  [Nautilus](https://github.com/GNOME/nautilus) probably does as well.  [Dolphin](https://github.com/KDE/dolphin) does not.  I don't know the exact rules they follow, but you can check their sources.

More at [How to tell if a SCSI device is removable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125961)

Comment: Thank you very much. With you help I was able to find the place in the source code. :) See my answer below if you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

PCManFM uses [GNOME GLib](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib) which has a [function `g_unix_mount_guess_should_display` in `gio/gunixmounts.c`](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/-/blob/718b5d5cd30a2464c19a6dcc338246fa8fa9f6b0/gio/gunixmounts.c#L2937) which defines the conditions for mountpoints to show up:

```
/* Never display internal mountpoints */

(...)
  
  /* Only display things in /media (which are generally user mountable)
     and home dir (fuse stuff) and /run/media/$USER */

(...)

      /* Hide mounts within a dot path, suppose it was a purpose to hide this mount */

(...)

      /* Check /run/media/$USER/. If running as root, display any mounts below
       * /run/media/. */

(...)

          /* Avoid displaying mounts that are not accessible to the user.
```

There's also an issue thread discussing changes to search in more places for mountpoints: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/-/issues/1043